# Check the zodiac signs sorted by month

Tags: java

There is a webpage that contains list of zodiacs sorted by month like`("Aries", "March 21 - April 19"),("Taurus", "April 20 - May 20"), ("Gemini", "May 21 - June 20"),("Cancer", "June 21 - July 22") .....`
    There is an option to add  some  zodiac signs to favorites and the favorite signs will be listed on the first with sorted order and the remaining zodiac will also be listed after the favorites in sorted order. 
    For eg i added following signs to favorites via UI

```
("Taurus", "April 20 - May 20"),("Libra", "September 23 - October 22"),("Aquarius", "January 20 - February 18")
```

And in UI it will be displayed in following manner

```
"Taurus", "April 20 - May 20"
"Libra", "September 23 - October 22"
"Aquarius", "January 20 - February 18"

"Aries", "March 21 - April 19"
"Gemini", "May 21 - June 20"
"Cancer", "June 21 - July 22"
"Leo", "July 23 - August 22"
"Virgo", "August 23 - September 22"
"Scorpio", "October 23 - November 21"
"Capricorn", "November 22 - December 21"
"Pisces", "February 19 - March 20"
```

My main aim is to verify the added favorites are sorted by month.Also the remaining zodiacs are also listed sorted by month.
and  verifing the sorted month from an `xml` file.After adding some zodiacs to favorites i will get an `xml` response that contains the list of zodiacs .and am parsing the xml for getting the zodiac sign with "March 21 - April 19"
and keeping it in a map.

```
Map<String,String> ZodiacMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

favorite zodiacs added

```
zodiacMap1.put("Taurus", "April 20 - May 20");
zodiacMap1.put("Libra", "September 23 - October 22");
zodiacMap1.put("Aquarius", "January 20 - February 18");
```

remaning zodiacs

```
zodiacMap1.put("Aries", "March 21 - April 19");
zodiacMap1.put("Gemini", "May 21 - June 20");
zodiacMap1.put("Cancer", "June 21 - July 22");
zodiacMap1.put("Leo", "July 23 - August 22");
zodiacMap1.put("Virgo", "August 23 - September 22");
zodiacMap1.put("Scorpio", "October 23 - November 21");
zodiacMap1.put("Capricorn", "November 22 - December 21");
zodiacMap1.put("Pisces", "February 19 - March 20");
```

From the map i need to verify the favorite zodiac are sorted by month also to verify the remining zodiac are sorted by month.

How it is pissible...????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many possible ways to do this. Here's one example.

Create a class called `Zodiac`, with fields:

- name, example value: "Gemini"
- month (of the start date), example value: 5 (for May)
- text, example value: "May 21 - June 20"

Also implement a `Comparator<Zodiac>`, which will compare `Zodiac` objects by their `.month` fields.

For example:

```
Comparator<Zodiac> byMonthComparator = new Comparator<>() {
    int compare(Zodiac o1, Zodiac o2) {
        return Integer.compare(o1.month, o2.month);
    }
}
```

Put the `Zodiac` instances in a `SortedSet`, using the custom comparator you just created. The items in such set will be sorted by month.

For example:

```
SortedSet<Zodiac> all = new TreeSet<>();
all.add(new Zodiac("Gemini", 5, "May 21 - June 20");
all.add(...);
...
```

Comment: using the logic u provided i think i can check the sorted order of the zodiacMap1 created from the xml response??? also is tthere any possible way to do with enum?

Comment: You could use two of those sorted sets one "static and full" one for all 12 and one which starts empty for the favorites.  To display enumerate all the favs, then loop through all the entries in the full set and display an entry if it is not also a member of favs